# Access Command Button Image - Scale to Button Size

Tags: image, vba, commandbutton

I have a Command Button object in on an Access form and I have set its .Picture property to reference an image.

Unfortunately, the image is too large to be fully displayed on the Command button. Is there a way of automatically resizing the image to fit the button size, whether that be through VBA or another Property which I haven't been able to find yet?

Thank you for your help in advance,

James